# Automatically run gulp tasks after saving some of javascript files in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, gulp

I have a folder in my asp.net project that contains some javascript files. Just before building project, they are minified and copied to "wwwroot" folder using gulp. It works great, but when I make some changes to any of javascript files, I have to restart entire project (to run tasks connected with building) or manually run tasks from "Task Runner Explorer".

It takes some time and it is quite irritating. Is it some way to run those tasks as soon as I save any of javascript files in this folder?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use `gulp.watch`. I've just migrated some build scripts from Grunt to Gulp, and wanted to provide the same functionality.

Just add a watch task to your Gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('/path/to/your/css/**/*.css', ['minifyCss']);
});
```

When you run this task gulp does not exit after the task is completed. Instead when a file changes, the task(s) specified in the second argument will run.
If you do not want to minify all CSS files when a file changes, `gulp-cached` package will come in handy. It filters files which are not modified since the task run last time (in a single Gulp running session, not between Gulp runs). Just add it after the `gulp.src` call in your task and it will filter the files which modified.

```
var cached = require('gulp-cached'),
    cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');

gulp.task('minifyCss', function() {
    return gulp.src('/path/to/your/css/**/*.css')
        .pipe(cached('cssFiles'))
        .pipe(cssnano()) // or whatever plugin you use for minification
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
}
```

I did try to run my task similar to this one from the VS Task Runner, but it does not like the ES6 features used in my Gulpfile so I do not know whether it is working fine with continuously running tasks. However it is working as intended from command line.

Comment: As gulp watch is based on chokidar it often throws EPERM errors when the file to be processes is not fully written and closed. This is because of how the windows / visual studio writes files.